# How NHibernate track changes made to the fields in my entity?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

How NHibernate track changes made to the fields in my entity? If I use second level cache and I change my entity, How does it apply my changes to db?

Comment: If you really want to know.. your best bet is to spend some time in the NH source code.. otherwise you should ask a question related to whatever problem caused you to raise this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change an entity, the entity becomes "dirty" and nhibernate knows the update the entity in your database when the session is flushed. That said, sometimes its possible for entities to get marked dirty even though you have made no change. This results in unnecessary update calls to your database.

It is best to isolate your entities from your views via view models. Once you pull an entity out of the database, convert it to a view model that you can mangle up.